# Python periodically refresh data from OWM

Tags: python, kivy, openweathermap

i built simple weather app using Kivy and OWM, but i ran into a problem. while program works fine, i got stuck on the way to reload (get again) data from OWM. I´ve tried `time.sleep()` but then i dont know how to remain app open. I didn´t find anything on internet, i tried googling but everything i could find was just event handling action. My guess is to use some sort of timer set to 2 minutes to call that function, but then how do i refresh Kivy app? So i want just the "`owm.get_weather()`" to be run every 2 minutes or so. Hope you understood. Thanks for help :) 
P.S. i forgot my code.. https://github.com/ApplePie420/OWMapp/blob/master/main.py

Answer (score 0):

kivy has a `Clock` object that you can use to schedule events for later.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyApp(App):
    # ...

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_data, 120)

    def update_data(self, *dt):
        # put here your code to load the data
        w = owm.get_weather()
        self.windLB = w.get_wind()['speed']
        # etc...
```